# MySQL SELECT issue - Probably simple

Tags: mysql

So I am currently facing an issue. I would like to Select a row (dlUser) from my Table. The issue is that when Active is set to 'No', we would re-use the dlUser number. I will try to explain using the example table below:

```
|     ID    |   Active  |   dlUser  |
-------------------------------------
|     1     |    Yes    |    100    |
|     2     |    No     |    100    |
|     3     |    No     |    101    |
|     4     |    No     |    101    |
```

So I want to select the dlUser where Active='No' but also where Active is not Yes. Therefore the output I would be looking to obtain here would be the dlUser:101 (As it is not currently "in use" and could therefore be used again). We can only have 1 of each dlUser number "Active" at any one time.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you could select the distinct values for `Active` for every `dlUser`. If the result only return `No`, as it would be the case for dlUser 101, you know you can reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to select the dlusers who are not listed as active on any row. This is an easy "NOT IN" query, where you select all the dlUsers who are "not in" the list of active users.

Try it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dlUser
FROM t
WHERE NOT dlUser NOT IN
(SELECT dlUser
 FROM t
 WHERE Active = 'Yes')
```

Comment: Hiya @kbball, 

This is returning both Active = Yes and Active = No values for some reason?

Any ideas as to why this would be the case?

EDITED THE COMMENT: Mixed up the two answers sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should satisfy my understanding of your question. In the table example you give it would only return dblUser 101.

```
SELECT a.dlUser 
FROM `yourtable` a 
WHERE a.Active = 'No' 
AND a.dblUser NOT IN (SELECT dlUser FROM `yourtable` WHERE a.Active = 'Yes') GROUP BY a.dlUser;
```

If you're building out what may become a very large table then I wouldn't recommend this method of doing it, because the queries will start to lag.

Comment: Your first WHERE clause isn't necessary, and you'll end up with duplicates if you don't use SELECT DISTINCT, but otherwise same idea

Comment: You're absolutely right about duplicates. Fixed it. Thanks. With regards to the first where clause, in some versions I get better results with an indexed restriction before a dynamic temp table restriction.

Comment: Hiya @Aunt Jamaima, Thanks for your reply.
This seems to be returning a value of zero, even though I am 100% confident there are dlUser numbers which are currently set to Active=No for all users.